# Создание виртуального окружения venv и установка Pyramid

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

Мне необходимо создать виртуальное окружение на ubuntu 14.04 согласно документации [установка Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html#installing-chapter). Проблема возникает при выполнении п.2 и п.3 абзаца **Installing Pyramid on a UNIX System**.
Выскакивает ошибка: `/home/ubuntu/MyDoc/bin/pip: No such file or directory`

Всё верно, pip отсутствует в этой папке. Но, я не отступаю от документации.

В документации к [venv](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/) описывается дерево папок и файлов, которые должны получится после применения команды `python3 -m venv $VENV`. В моём случае не хватает `pysetup3`,а выскакивает ошибка

> The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
>   available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
>   package using the following command.
>       apt-get install python3-venv
>   You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
>   package, recreate your virtual environment.

Т.е. отсутствует python3-venv.

Что сделано не верно?

Comment: Добавил информацию по ошибке

Comment: venv и virtualenv это разные вещи с похожей целью. Потренируйтесь с [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io), чтобы освоиться.

Comment: Спасибо. Но я вроде не мешал две "вещи". Сразу стало понятно, что работая с python3, мне нужно запускать **venv**.

Comment: посмотрите на метку в вопросе. Из того что вы используете python3 вовсе не следует, что venv обязательно нужно использовать. `virtualenv` не ограничен только Питон 2.

Comment: Да, к сожалению я не могу создать метку. А более близкой метки, которая уже создана, не имеется.  По поводу Python 3, нужно было сказать python3.4 и выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ находится тут на англоязычном [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271982/install-python3-venv-module-on-linux-mint)
При установке python-venv необходимо ввести индекс предустановленного в систему Ubuntu **Python**.
В данном случае - это python3.4.

Код

`sudo apt-get install python3.4-venv`

После этого ошибок, которые описаны в вопросе не возникает.

Comment: Я к сожалению просто писал `sudo apt-get install python3-venv`